# Using Opencv 3.1 from CAFFE

Tags: opencv, caffe

I am trying to use OPENCV 3.1 from inside of the caffe . This is my test code

```
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>
#ifdef USE_OPENCV
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#endif  // USE_OPENCV
#include<iostream>

#ifdef USE_OPENCV

int main(){
    std::cout<<"USE_OPENCV value is 1\n";
    return 0;
}
#else
int main(){
    std::cout<<"USE_OPENCV value is 0\n";
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

I am compiling it using following command

```
 g++ -I path_to_caffe/distribute/include/  test3.cpp -std=c++0x  -lboost_system
```

It compiles with giving the following output while executing :

> USE_OPENCV value is 0

Before compiling the caffe i make this changes in Makefile.config file:

```
USE_OPENCV := 1
. . .
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
. . .
USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1
```

While compiling caffe, I  firstly cleand it and then compiled it using following commands:

```
make clean
make all -j $(($(nproc) + 1))
make test
make runtest
make pycaffe 
make distribute
```

It compiles without giving error , but while testing my test file it does not gives the output that i expect.

Comment: `g++ -I /home/nail/caffe-rc5/distribute/include/  test3.cpp -std=c++0x  -lboost_system -DUSE_OPENCV`

Comment: @Shai you are the best that simple thing teased me much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All glories goes to Shai. The solution is to add -DUSE_OPENCV flag .

```
g++ -I path_to_caffe/distribute/include/ test3.cpp -std=c++0x -lboost_system -DUSE_OPENCV
```